# Affine Transform for n-sided polygon

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I was going through this question for the explanation of affine transform for a quadrilateral - [trying to understand the Affine Transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667834/trying-to-understand-the-affine-transform)

However, I want to perform affine transform for perspective correction of a n-sided polygon, for any n (obviously > 3). Can anyone please explain me how to do it or suggest a OpenCV [or something similar] implementation so that I can implement it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so your input is a n-sided polygon in 2 images and you want to find the affine transformation between the images, or is your input a n-sided polygon and a transformation and you want to compute the transformed polygon?

Comment: And note that affine transform cannot correct perspective deformation.