# image resize in image stitching pipeline

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, panoramas, image-stitching

OpenCV contains one image stitching module. The pipeline is followed
[image]

There is one step named Resize. As I understand, the step is added in order to reduce computation because feature detection for one big image may need a lot of time. However, the homography calculated from one pair of two smaller images can't apply to the original images. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Since the homography matrix can be perceived as a transformation matrix; the homography matrix which is estimated for the scaled image can be used with original size image as well.

`H_orig = H_scale * H_estimated` is a valid operation. You can read more about the homography matrix and what its components stand for from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21019338/how-to-change-the-homography-with-the-scale-of-the-image/48915151#48915151) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667834/trying-to-understand-the-affine-transform/).

Comment: From the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21019338/how-to-change-the-homography-with-the-scale-of-the-image/48915151#48915151, Hs is not same as H in the second answer.